# How do I reference projects in the same solution in Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, reference

I have a solution that contains 1 project.  In that project I added existing projects (class libraries) from a different file location on my computer.  Now that I have added those existing projects to my solution I can add them as References to my original project in the solution.

Everything works just great, except now when I try to access my web application on my azure site, I get problems.  Im thinking because azure is somehow not getting my local references.

Can anyone help me think this one out?  What am i missing, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you verified the libraries you referenced are included in your deployment directory within Azure? You can FTP into your Azure site directory by following instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/#create-a-web-app-and-set-up-ftp-publishing).

If the libraries are not included in your deployment directory, check your solution under references, and verify "Copy Local" is set to true. Redeploy and try it again.

If that still doesn't work, you can enable logging in Azure and access the logs via the same FTP login as above.

Hope this helps!